# My Java program doesn't iterate through my entire CSV file

Tags: java, csv

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dataReader {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String splitBy =",";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/practice/testData.csv"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int counter = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            counter++;
            String[] b = line.split(splitBy);

            for (int x = 0; x < b.length; x++){
                System.out.println(b[x]);
            }


        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        br.close();
    }   
}
```

When I run it, it goes through the CSV and displays some output but it starts with product ID 4000+. It basically only outputs results for the last thousand rows in the CSV. I'm wrangling with a really ugly CSV file to try to get some useful data out of it so that I can write all of it into a new database later on. I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: You're using `System.out.println` to output, and only seeing the last ~1000 rows. Are you sure the issue isn't your console limit? Seems bold to scroll that far back.

Comment: This is exactly it. I add a counter variable so that the while loop runs only 1000 times, and I get the output from the beginning of the file too. Thanks!

Comment: Kevin, do you want to write that as an answer so I can accept it as the official answer?

Comment: No problems, glad to help. Added the answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments, the issue is that `System.out.println` prints to your console. The console will have a limit to the number of lines it can display, which is why you see the last ~1000 lines.

Answer (score 2):

At a frist glance at your code, you skip the first line by assigning a readline() to your string line

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

You should change that as you read the first line and than enter the loop which will read the 2nd line before any operations on the first line took place.

Try something like

```
String line = "";
```

Comment: This solves an issue with discarding the first row. The real problem was the fact that the console only displays ~1000 rows at a time, like the gentleman in the comments mentioned. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't handle more complicated CSVs, eg a row:

> "Robert, John", 25, "Chicago, IL"

is not going to get parsed correctly. Just splitting on ',' is going to separate "Robert, John" into multiple cells though it should be just 1 cell.

The point is, you shouldn't be writing a CSV parser. I highly recommend go downloading the [Apache Commons CSV library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) and using that! Reading CSVs is a solved problem; why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I just started having that type of problem. My parser stopped grabbing half of the lines once they started having extra commas. Thanks for the heads up, I'll check out that library.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. That library is amazing and it's working beautifully. I didn't even know I needed it until I saw firsthand what happens when you rely on just a comma. It's amazing how much more productive I can become when more experienced people share their knowledge. And I look forward to doing the same thing for other newbs down the road. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the structure of the file I can only speculate, but this line: `String line = br.readLine();` needs to be changed to `String line = ""` or `String line = null`. As it currently stands, you are discarding your first line.